# User registration confirmation mail in Loopback

Tags: angularjs, node.js, mongodb, loopbackjs, email-verification

I'm trying to send verification mail to the user when registered .I'm using angular as frontend and nodejs , mongoDb and loopback in the backend.
This is my html registration form.

```
     <form class="form-signin" name="frm" role="form" accept-charset="UTF-8" novalidate>
     <fieldset>
        <input type="email" name="email" id="email" ng-model="profile.email" required>
        <input type="submit"  ng-submit value="Sign Up"   ng-click="register()">
    </fieldset>
  </form>
```

And the following is the code in register controller

```
    $scope.register = function() {
    $scope.profile.createTS = new Date();
    $scope.profile.username = $scope.profile.email;
    $scope.profile.id = uuid.v4();
    $scope.profile.created = new Date();
    $scope.profile.lastUpdated = new Date();
    AppUser.create($scope.profile,function() {
    $location.path('/login');

    }
   };
```

And I added these details in datasourses.json

```
    "emailDs": {
    "name": "emailDs",
    "connector": "mail",
    "transports": [{
     "type": "smtp",
     "host": "n1plcpnl0010.prod.ams1.secureserver.net",
     "secure": true,
     "port": 465,
     "tls": {
      "rejectUnauthorized": false
      },
    "auth": {
    "user":"support@mycompany.com",
    "pass": "password"
       }
     }]
    }
```

And the following code , I added in app-user.js

```
    AppUser.afterRemote('create', function(context, AppUser) {
    console.log('> AppUser.afterRemote triggered');

    var options = {
    type: 'email',
    to: AppUser.email,
    from: 'support@mycompany.com',
    subject: 'Thanks for registering.',
     template: path.resolve(__dirname, '../../../telekha-web/app/views/login.html'),
   redirect: 'http://172.17.0.1:9000/login',
   user: AppUser
   };

   AppUser.verify(options, function(err, response) {
   if (err) {
     next(err);
     return;
   }

   console.log('> verification email sent:', response);
   context.res.render('response', {
    title: 'Signed up successfully',
    content: 'Please check your email and click on the verification link ' +
        'before logging in.',
    redirectTo: 'http://172.17.0.1:9000/login',
    redirectToLinkText: 'Log in'
  });

 });
 });
```

Users can register with this code.But, verification mail is not being sent to the user. Do I need to add anything in my view ? I also added instance for email in model-config.js

Please Help!!

Comment: As @Rik said verify that your email datasource is well configured.

Answer (score 0):

I made it work with this settings:

```
model-config.json

  "Email":{
    "dataSource":"Email"
  }

datasources.json

"Email": {
    "name": "email",
    "defaultForType": "mail",
    "connector": "mail",
    "transports": [
      {
        "type": "SMTP",
        "host": "abc.com",
        "secureConnection": true,
        "port": 587,
        "auth": {
          "user": "mail@abc.com",
          "pass": "pass"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
```

Two things to point out:
1)Try using `port 587` in datasources.json 
2)Try using `"Email"` as name for model and in datasource. (Instead of `emailDs` )

I can send email this way from local server (using hMailServer and this tutorial: https://www.hmailserver.com/documentation/latest/?page=howto_set_up_local)